# Meaning of “l'égalité sans distinction de”

Tags: sens, prépositions

I don't think I'm able to translate this correctly (unless it is what it actually means to say). What is the meaning of 'sans' in this context?

> Elle assure l'égalité devant la loi de tous les citoyens sans distinction d'origine, de race ou de religion.

Comment: Welcome to French Language. Please visit the [Help Centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help), you will see this: [What is the meaning of this word? We do ask that you look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first.](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So please do not say "I don't think i have translated correctly (unless it is what it actually means to say)." but say what you think it means and why you hesitate about the meaning in this sentence.

Answer (score 3):

"Sans distinction de" corresponds to the English "without distinction of". Here is a possible translation: "It guarantees that all citizens are equal before the law without distinction of origin, race or religion."

This sentence is from the French Constitution, whose official translation is provided in [this page](https://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/sites/default/files/as/root/bank_mm/anglais/constitution_anglais.pdf): "It shall ensure the equality of all citizens before the law, without distinction of origin, race or religion."

Comment: I'd rather say *Irrespective of their origin etc.* But it might well be just me. And... considering the link you provide... : It's just me. (+1)

Comment: @aCOSwt — Peut-être… mais depuis que les Anglais ne cesse de guerroyer contre les hexagonaux, ces derniers ne ratent pas une occasion  d’affirmer qu’*irrespectueux* est une notion morale, alors que *distinction*, en dehors du sens donné par les mœurs, est une capacité subtile de discerner des détails entre des faits ou états établis… :-)

Comment: Like aCOSwt, I wouldn’t say “without distinction of,” but instead of “irrespective of,” I would say “regardless of” or “without regard to.”

Comment: @Steeve: Words in a constitution have tremendous weight. You can't freely change them to something else just because it's more idiomatic in the target language. It is usually better to keep as literal as possible. Note that if the French phrasing was “sans tenir compte de” (which hopefully it isn't), it would have a whole lot of different implications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [complete article](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexteArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000019240997&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006071194&dateTexte=20080725#targetText=La%20France%20est%20une%20R%C3%A9publique,Son%20organisation%20est%20d%C3%A9centralis%C3%A9e.):

> La France est une République indivisible, laïque, démocratique et sociale. Elle assure l'égalité devant la loi de tous les citoyens sans distinction d'origine, de race ou de religion. Elle respecte toutes les croyances. Son organisation est décentralisée.
>
> La loi favorise l'égal accès des femmes et des hommes aux mandats électoraux et fonctions électives, ainsi qu'aux responsabilités professionnelles et sociales.

There is also a recent updated version as it is thoroughly discussed [here](https://www.lemonde.fr/politique/article/2018/07/12/l-assemblee-supprime-dans-la-constitution-le-mot-race-et-interdit-la-distinction-de-sexe_5330615_823448.html)

> Premier amendement adopté, fortement symbolique, au projet de révision
> de la loi fondamentale : les députés ont supprimé à l’unanimité le mot
> « race » et interdit toute « distinction de sexe ».

[In particular](http://www.lefigaro.fr/politique/le-scan/2018/07/13/25001-20180713ARTFIG00165-les-deputes-inscrivent-l-environnement-a-l-article-1er-de-la-constitution.php) the article is now

> La France est une République indivisible, laïque, démocratique et sociale. Elle assure l'égalité devant la loi de tous les citoyens sans distinction de sexe, d'origine ou de religion.

DeepL translates this as

> France is an indivisible, secular, democratic and social Republic. It ensures the equality before the law of all citizens without distinction as to sex, origin or religion.